# Dump CPP data into file to reuse later

Tags: c++, dictionary, inverted-index

I am working over one problem where I need to store some calculated data in CPP (map data) for future reference so that it can later be used by directly loading it into memory. (Somewhat similar to pickle in python)
What will be the fastest way to achieve this.

Comment: U wanna  store the calculated data on your hard drive, right?

Comment: @Arunava yes. I want to store that in hard drive, so that it can be reused.

Comment: I answered, if you are facing any problem then comment, I'll try to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Compile your program with

```
g++ -o output.o program.cpp
```

[Considering `program.cpp` is in the current working directory]

Then, while executing

```
./output.o > output.txt
```

This would store your output from `program.cpp` in `output.txt` for future reference.

Comment: I am not sure about output.o > output.txt because I want to store let say map data into a file and also want to later reuse it by directly loading it into the map preferably without doing much operation (like direct loading file data into map). Anyway I will try your option as well. Thanks

Comment: I have used pickle library in python that does the same. But I was looking something for CPP.